# fill out drupal webform automatically

Tags: php, drupal, phpmyadmin, drupal-webform

How do I fill out my drupal webform automatically, I have 500 entries to fill out and I can't do it one by one. I try to fill it out automatically directly to phpmyadmin in drupal Database but it doesn't work beacause drupal add more fields in his database (in webform_ submitted_data) so I think it's possible to use a script or use a module to fill it out but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best module to do it, it's [webform import](https://drupal.org/project/webform_import) very helpful

Allows delimited data files to be imported as submission (results) into webforms.

This is useful for importing submissions from other systems in to Webform. Can also be used to Edit submissions via Export / Import as long as the CSV has the SID column filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drupal_form_submit() to submit a webform. See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/76965) over at drupal.stackexchange.com for instructions.

When you've got that working, it should just be a matter of looping over the webforms you want to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox module for that: [Webform Autofill](https://drupal.org/sandbox/jacintocapote/1857378). But I 've never used it so I can be sure it works.

If you have never used a sandbox module you can see more details at the [drupal sandbox modules documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1294804).